# ANSYS scripting: defining global reference coordinate system

Tags: python, scripting, ansys

I am trying to write a Python script in an ANSYS Transient structural Problem to define a joint. I have written the code to create a joint and define all elements of it except the origin.
In the joint, the reference coordinate system has origin by default to be defined by geometry selection.
I am not able to find the command to change it to global coordinates. What is the Python script command to change it to Global coordinates?

Please note that I need only Python script command that can be directly run in editor to change it to global coordinates.

My current code to create a joint is:

```
joint1=DataModel.Project.Model.Connections.AddJoint()
joint1.ConnectionType=JointScopingType.BodyToGround
named_selection1=DataModel.GetObjectsByName("XYZ")
joint1.PromoteToNamedSelection()
joint1.MobileLocation=named_selection[0]
joint1.Type=JointType.General
joint1.TranslationX=FixedOrFree.Free
joint1.TranslationY=FixedOrFree.Free
joint1.TranslationZ=FixedOrFree.Free
joint1.ReferenceCoordinateSystem.PrimaryAxisDefineBy=CoordinateSystemAlignmentType.GlobalZ
joint1.ReferenceCoordinateSystem.SecondaryAxisDefineBy=CoordinateSystemAlignmentType.GlobalY
```

Answer (score 0):

This should switch the Origin definition to Global Coordinates:

```
joint1.ReferenceCoordinateSystem.OriginDefineBy =  CoordinateSystemAlignmentType.Fixed
```